# Is the convolution of $L^2$ and $L^2\setminus L^1$ in $L^2$, and is Fourier transform of convolution equal to product of Fourier Transforms

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Let $f\in L^2(\Bbb{R})$, and for each $0<r<\infty$, define $\phi_r:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ by
\begin{align}
\phi_r(y):=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{y} &\text{if $r<|y|<\infty$}\\
0& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
In this case, we have $\phi_r\in L^2\setminus L^1$. My question is whether it is even true that $f*\phi_r\in L^2$, and if it is, whether it is true that the Fourier transform satisfies $\widehat{f*\phi_r}= \widehat{f}\cdot \widehat{\phi_r}$.

Of course, if $g\in L^1$, then Young's inequality tells us $\lVert f*g\rVert_2\leq \lVert f\rVert_2\cdot \lVert g\rVert_1$, and we also have $\widehat{f*g}=\hat{f}\cdot \hat{g}$. But I'm struggling to determine what happens under the weaker hypotheses above where $\phi_r\in L^2\setminus L^1$.

Context: this question arose as part of a larger calculation related to the Hilbert transform (namely that if we define for $f\in L^2$, $Hf:= \left[\text{sgn}(\cdot)\cdot \hat{f}\right]^{\vee}$, then I'm trying to show that $\lVert Hf-\frac{-1}{i\pi}f*\phi_r\rVert_2\to 0$ as $r\to 0^+$; my main idea is to use Parseval's identity and then explicitly calculate $\widehat{\phi_r}$).

Comment: How are you looking to define the Fourier transform here? As the abstract operator on $L^2$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes, the one which is obtained by extending the definition from $L^1\cap L^2$ (using the integral) via continuity.

Comment: Check this out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605232/fourier-transform-of-convolution-for-l2-functions

Comment: @CameronWilliams that was something I actually learnt before, but forgot, so thank you for bringing that to my attention! Although my conjecture that I wrote down is not true in general, in my specific case, I can explicitly calculate the Fourier transform of $\phi_r$, and I know it is a bounded function, so from the identity (given in that post) $f*\phi_r = \left[\widehat{f}\cdot \widehat{\phi_r}\right]^{\vee}$, the RHS is the product of the $L^2$ function $\hat{f}$ with the bounded $\widehat{\phi_r}$, hence the product is in $L^2$, so the inverse transform brings it back to $L^2$ again :)